# Using angular-cli to build a library other projects can install

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Here is a little background:

I created an angular-cli (beta 17) project for my organization that contains several components I'd like to share with other Angular 2 projects in the organization.

I started out keeping it simple, just using npm to install the GitHub repo into an implementation app and importing the components. I thought this was going to work as it compiled just fine, but running the app in the browser produced a 404 error when the template HTML file for the imported component could not be found.

I even tried using inline HTML templates within the component's definition, but it was still trying to find the HTML file.

Is there a good way to use angular-cli to build a component library app in a way that would allow other projects to install and use it? If not, what would be a good alternative? Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is currently not supported by the Angular CLI, but it is on the roadmap to be supported in the future.

The current process I've seen followed for libraries is a custom build process. I would suggest finding a library that you've used via npm, track it back to github, where it is likely maintained, and politely *borrow* their project structure. The main feature right now to ensure it supports is AoT compilation, your users will thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what this feature would be called in the CLI roadmap? I'd like to watch for it.

Comment: `Library support` would be the gist, not sure of the actual title/text

Answer (score 6):

Look into Ng-packagr, it can integrated into an Angular CLI project and used to export component libraries from it using the Angular Package Format. For a simple tutorial, see https://medium.com/@ngl817/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

Answer (score 1):

As @Brocco mentioned there is no such feature yet, but it is going to be (see [discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1692)).

**So for now I suggest to create lib based on this [sample](https://github.com/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-lib).** (this [diff commit](https://github.com/nsmolenskii/ng-demo-lib/commit/219839423bf272e1ddc12d072a1f7c4314917a22?diff=split) is showing what needs to be done)